# How to set a custom TAlphaColor programmatically?

Tags: delphi, colors, firemonkey

That's basically how I attribute `colors` programatically in `Delphi`

```
label.FontColor      := TAlphaColors.Yellow;
```

What if I want a custom color like `#FF1C90EF`?

How can I set it *programatically*?

Comment: `label.FontColor := $FF1C90EF;`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you can pass the color to a new instance of [`TAlphaColor`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE7/en/System.UITypes.TAlphaColor)

Eg, `TAlphaColor($FF1C90EF)`.

Having said that, you can also just set the `.FontColor` property directly without creating a new instance of `TAlphaColor`.

Comment: Wouldn't it be `TAlphaColor($FF1C90EF);` ?

Comment: @Holmes It would, yes. I fixed it.

Answer (score 8):

Similar to `TColor` in VCL, `TAlphaColor` is just an integer (well, a `Cardinal` anyway), so you can type-cast your hex value directly:

```
label.FontColor := TAlphaColor($FF1C90EF);
```

This behavior is documented on Embarcadero's DocWiki:

[System.UITypes.TAlphaColor](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Seattle/en/System.UITypes.TAlphaColor)

> There are three ways to set a color:
>
> - Using the predefined constants from System.UIConsts:
>
>   ```
>   Color := claGreen; //Delphi
>   Color = TAlphaColor(claGreen); // C++
>   ```
> - Using the predefined constants from TAlphaColorRec:
>
>   ```
>   Color := TAlphaColorRec.Green; //Delphi
>   Color = TAlphaColor(TAlphaColorRec::Green); // C++
>   ```
> - Using the 4-byte hexadecimal number representation:
>
>   ```
>   Color := $FF008000;  // Delphi
>   Color = TAlphaColor(0xFF008000); // C++
>   ```

You can also use the `TAlphaColorRec` record to assign the individual components:

```
var
  rec: TAlphaColorRec;
begin
  rec.A := $FF;
  rec.R := $1C;
  rec.G := $90;
  rec.B := $EF;
  label.FontColor := rec.Color;
end;
```

Comment: There is also TAlphaColors.Green

Comment: Why I am getting `Range check error` with TAlphaColorRec.Green ?

Comment: @SAMPro there is no `TAlphaColorRec.Green`, did you mean `TAlphaColorRec.G` or `TAlphaColors.Green`? What does your code look like that is erroring?