# change form color (FMX, Win32)

Tags: firemonkey, c++builder

I'm making an FMX app for Win32 (one form only) with C++ Builder 10.2 update 3.  How can i change the form's background from grey to white?  I can't edit the form's style like i can other controls.

I tried the following based [on this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33760430/how-to-set-a-custom-talphacolor-programmatically) but it had no effect.

```
Form1->Fill->Color = TAlphaColor(TAlphaColorRec::White);
```

I know i can just add a `TRectangle` to the form (aligned to client with HitTest false) and just set it's color.  But i'd rather just use the form itself if not overly complicated.

thanks,
russ

Comment: You need to also set Form1->Fill->Kind to solid.

Comment: Thanks Doug - that did the trick.  Added `Form1->Fill->Kind = TBrushKind::Solid;` and life is good.