# TAlphacolor in Integer to convert to Alphacolor description

Tags: delphi, colors, firemonkey

I obtained a value of `-65536` from the RTTI inspector for `Red`.

1. How do I convert it into a constant description of `Red` without duplicating all the members of the `TAlphaColorRec` record into an array?
2. How do I set `ColorCombobox1.Color := ... somefunction(-65536)` that `TColorCombobox` knows it is `Red`?

From Delphi source:

```
TAlphaColorRec = record
const
  Alpha = TAlphaColor($FF000000);
  Aliceblue = Alpha or TAlphaColor($F0F8FF);
  Antiquewhite = Alpha or TAlphaColor($FAEBD7);
  Aqua = Alpha or TAlphaColor($00FFFF);
```

I read [How to set a custom TAlphaColor programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33760430/) but it does not have what I need.

Comment: Decimal `-65536` is hex `$FFFF0000`. `TAlphaColorRec.Red` is defined as `TAlphaColorRec.Alpha or TAlphaColor($FF0000)`, where `TAlphaColorRec.Alpha` is defined as `TAlphaColor($FF000000)`. Hence `TAlphaColorRec.Red` is `TAlphaColor($FFFF0000)`. So, just use a type-cast, you don't need a function: `ColorCombobox1.Color := TAlphaColor(-65536);` (just as I stated in my previous answer, which you dismissed as "not having what I need"). So, what exactly DO you need? Please be more specific.

Comment: @RemyLebeau the typecast you gave above is exactly what I need.  Thanks so much! my apologies, I didn't mean it as "dismissing" but I wanted to show what I have searched so far in case people think I post a simple question without researching.  I didn't know the integer can be typecast such as hex value (which was the example given).  One thing I'm curious is I thought TAlphacolor is a cardinal value but -65536 is negative.

Comment: The truth was that I actually quoted the link with your answer to show that it was the most detailed answer on TAlphaColor I could find. :)  Yet I was still puzzled how to cast the integer into a TAlphaColor, which you have kindly explained.

Answer (score 4):

I think what you're looking for in question #1 is [`AlphaColorToString()`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/System.UIConsts.AlphaColorToString) in the `System.UIConsts` unit.

Comment: hi Philip, thanks for this.  I was looking in the wrong .pas file.